# RNSScreen" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

I'm attempting my first EAS build, and I keep running into this error:
Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreen" was not found in the UIManager.

I have followed troubleshooting in StackOverflow and other sources, which indicates I should install react-native-screens which I have done. I have also uninstalled and reinstalled node modules multiple times. Below is my package.json . Any guidance would be much appreciated!

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.23.4",
    "@googlemaps/js-api-loader": "^1.16.2",
    "@mapbox/polyline": "^1.2.1",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
    "@react-native-community/blur": "^4.3.2",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "7.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.73.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.11",
    "@react-navigation/elements": "^1.3.21",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.17",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.20",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.7",
    "@rneui/base": "^4.0.0-rc.7",
    "@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.8",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.38",
    "axios": "^1.6.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "expo": "^49.0.21",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.8.3",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.4.12",
    "expo-location": "~16.1.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "firebase": "^10.6.0",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
    "openai": "^4.20.0",
    "pexels": "^1.4.0",
    "pg": "^8.11.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1302.0",
    "react-native-deck-swiper": "^2.0.16",
    "react-native-draggable-flatlist": "^4.0.1",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.6.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "~1.9.0",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-maps": "1.7.1",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^17.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.3",
    "typescript": "^5.3.2",
    "url-polyfill": "^1.1.12",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.3",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.7",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2"
  },
```

eas build --profile development --platform ios

ERROR  Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreen" was not found in the UIManager.

This error is located at:
in RNSScreen
in Unknown (created by InnerScreen)
in Suspender (created by Freeze)
in Suspense (created by Freeze)
in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
in Screen (created by MaybeScreen)
in MaybeScreen (created by CardStack)
in RNSScreenContainer (created by ScreenContainer)
in ScreenContainer (created by MaybeScreenContainer)
in MaybeScreenContainer (created by CardStack)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by Background)
in Background (created by CardStack)
in CardStack (created by HeaderShownContext)
in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by StackView)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by GestureHandlerRootView)
in GestureHandlerRootView (created by StackView)
in StackView (created by StackNavigator)
in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
in NavigationContent
in Unknown (created by StackNavigator)
in StackNavigator (created by AppNav)
in EnsureSingleNavigator
in BaseNavigationContainer
in ThemeProvider
in NavigationContainerInner (created by AppNav)
in AppNav (created by App)
in Provider (created by App)
in App (created by withDevTools(App))
in withDevTools(App)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
in main(RootComponent), js engine: hermes